# Add NSArray to CLBeaconRegion via setValue forKey causes Error

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsarray, ibeacon

Is it possible to add an Array to a `CLBeaconRegion` via a `setValue forKey`?

I've tried to add it:

```
[regionAdvert setValue:haveArray forKey:@"advertArray"];
```

But I receive just the following error:

```
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
> reason: '[<CLBeaconRegion 0x15379600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
> class is not key value coding-compliant for the key advertArray.'
```

Comment: You want to associated an arbitrary object with the region?

Comment: So, it's not possible to do that? I was confused, because xcode suggested it to me. :S

Comment: Why don't you use the `major`, `minor` properties to identify the region?

Comment: @Wain The identification isn't a problem. I want to add data to the region. For example, only open an alertview, if the region has an array with the object abc in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setValue:forKey:` is a [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) method which is basically available on every class - but that doesn't mean you can just pass anything to it. The key you use needs to be an existing property (well, really a method as that is what gets called, or a handled non-existent key). Anyway, the point is that you should know the key exists before trying to set it.

Technically you can use `objc_setAssociatedObject` to associated arbitrary objects with other objects but in this case I would encourage you to instead use the `major` and `minor` properties to check the purpose of the region before deciding how to display your alert.

Comment: Thx for your answer. How can I "set" a key? I only know it the way I did.

Comment: If you had `@property (strong) NSString *myString;` that would add the key `myString` to your class (and some accessor methods). When you call `setValue:forKey:` it gets translated into `setMyString:` (which is one of the accessor methods created for you by the property).

Comment: It still causes the error. Btw: How can I edit the major-value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39679/discussion-between-c0dev-and-wain)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.  If you want to associate other data with a CLBeaconRegion, then you can use  other data structures like NSDictionary.  Since each CLBeaconRegion is constructed with a unique "identifier" string, you can use this identifier as a key into a NSDictionary to store your other arbitrary data objects.

Also, you aren't supposed to change a CLBeaconRegion once constructed. The fields are immutable. This isn't really a big deal -- there are only three fields. Just create a new CLBeaconRegion, copying any of the identifiers from the old CLBeaconRegion that you wish to retain.